# Designing classes in c#

Tags: c#

Suppose we want to model a doctor's patient: a patient has a prescription history, an appointment history, a test results history... Each of these items is itself a list.

What's the best way to create the patient class?

```
class MyPatient{
   List<Prescription> Prescriptions {get;set;}
   List<Appoints> Appoints {get;set;}
   ...
}

class Prescription{
   string PrescripName {get;set}
   int Dosage {get;set}
}

class PatientAppoint{...}
```

This is what I have in mind; please let me know if you have some suggestions.

Comment: I assume prescriptions come from an appointment.. need that link !

Comment: I prefer your method(composing objects into other objects) is the best option, since you might need to evolve those objects as the project goes on.

Comment: Actually, think of a doctor looking at a dashboard of his patients.

Comment: Not sure why your title refers to this as "defining _nested_ class". There are no nested classes here. Also, note that your properties in `MyPatient` do not have names.  You probably want something like `List<Presciption> Prescriptions {get; set;}`.

Comment: @frenchie still not sure what the question is, there is nothing wrong with your **design** apart from the syntax errors @joel points out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of things to take into account when designing your classes:

1. Inheritence vs Composition -- Use "Is A" and "Has A".
   For example, a `Car` **is a** `Vehicle`. A `Car` **has a** `Engine`.
2. Don't throw in a bunch of junk into a class to try to make it work for another class.
   For example, if you want a Prescription **history** you'll probably need a Prescription and a Date. But, don't throw a Date into Prescription if it doesn't fit in, instead, extend it to a new PrescriptionHistoryItem class which inherits from Prescription.
3. Start off with an abstract representation or contractual representation and build off of that. You don't need to end up keeping any abstract classes or interfaces if they are unnecessary, but they might help you on the way there.

Basically, there are a lot of things to consider and this question is pretty open ended. There are way too many design patterns and topics to consider and that are debatable. Overall, your class hierarchy/design looks fine though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping all classes in a file , i would create a separate file for each class with the same name. It will be easy for future programmer to debug or it will be very clean to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is a pretty standard way of representing those objects in OOP.  Your patients have a one to many relationship with both prescriptions and appointments, so you patient class has a collection of each. You may want to keep how you are going to persist you data (database I assume) in mind as you design your class structures and layout.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example of where the model can become problematic at runtime. As you start to draw this out, you may end up with a collection of patients at somepoint. If you have data adapters building patients, and stuffing the prescription, visit, test, etc. histories into the patient classes, then a collection of Patients can end up being quite large. Now if this large collection is being transported over a network, say, between a WCF service and a client, it could become burdensome. For example, if you are just displaying a list of patients...

So in my opinion, I would look at the system from a slightly higher level, and consider some of the things I mentioned above. If you are going to be passing around collections with 500 patients in them, then I might consider a model that allows me to associate patients and "item" histories when necessary, but also be able to have them separated when desired...

This would affect the model, in my opinion, because I don't like to design a class where when the data adapter builds the instance, the population of fields is arbitrary, that is, sometimes it populates them sometimes it doesn't... But I have done that before... ;)

Comment: I do plan to have collections of 500+ patients. And each patient stands to have 9 lists attached to it. Can you explain what could go wrong with my class design?

Comment: Hi Frenchie. The potential issue is that a collection of patients can become very large. If it is necessary to have all the patient data for all patients at all times, that the model is appropriate. however, if, as I suggested above, there are times when the attached histories are needed and times when they are not, then I would separate them out, almost in the same manner that they would be separated in a database. The issue that I see is the transfer of very large datasets, in cases when not all the data is needed, such as when displaying a simple list of patients.

Comment: I'm planning on using a json cache to store the data. The function that initially returns all the sub-models to compose the collection of models will pass the composed collection of MyPatients to a json encoder that'll store each MyPatient in a json string format in an index database table that'll look like a dictionary. What do you think of doing that?